# Titanium - Securely store information on device

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I would like to store token and other user information securely on the device. From my understanding just using the regular preferences is not secure, and on iOS such data should be stored in KeyChain (android should still save in SharedPrefrences).

Does Titanium have an API for storing information in iOS Keychain?

I also found OSS module on Marketplace that does that: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/4112?restoreSearch=true#!overview

But if there's native platform support I rather use it.

Comment: You could store information any where on the device, just encrypt it. There are a lot of ways to do this.

Comment: @VladimirKulyk if you encrypt you probably save the key also somewhere on the device... what prevents someone from reverse engineering an app and get that key?

Comment: you can define this key in the code, or generate using device id at runtime each time you need to decrypt this data.

Comment: @VladimirKulyk since code is reversible I wouldn't store that in code. Even if you generate this key based on device id, or some other random string, you would still need to store it someplace secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API with `Titanium` to store data in Keychain, but you can use this module : https://github.com/pegli/ti_keychain/tree/master/mobile

Comment: Looks like the same module that I founs in marketplace. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I use this one : https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Securely for my project